# How to update OpenOffice Calc sheets with new formulas and formats?

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have created a spreadsheet in OpenOffice Calc that has multiple sheets for each month of the year. The sheet has some specific formulas and data laid out in several months.

Is there any easy way to go about modifying a formula and having it transfer across all the sheets?

Or if the format changes, is there a way to merge sheets through some type of macro or something?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is laid out in a very regular way, you may be able to copy+paste the modified formula to each sheet and have it adjust the cell references correctly.

However, for this type of flexibility (being able to make a change in one location and have it reflected in how all existing data is displayed) a database is generally required.  OpenOffice has a database component Base, and information from Base can easily be imported to Calc if you have specific spreadsheet requirements.  The learning curve for Base is fairly long, but might be worthwhile if you handle this kind of data frequently.

Answer (score 0):

A formula in the same place on several sheets need only be updated once provided the relevant sheets are grouped together first (click their tabs with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> depressed - and don't forget to ungroup them when appropriate!). Fill applied to A1 of a group of sheets will colour A1 in each of those sheets.

The Consolidate feature (under Data) might be of interest.